# Excel price function not working despite adding the analysis tool pack

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2003, finance

I am trying to price bonds using the Excel function, PRICE(..), but the intellisense doesn't come up. The [help file](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel/HP052092191033.aspx) says to install the analysis tool pack, but this doesn't resolve the problem. I have Office 2003 for XP.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to use it in a worksheet function, go to Tools - Addins and select Analysis Toolpak.  Make sure there's a checkbox next to it before you click OK.  You can't just select it (highlight), you have to click the box (green check).

If you're trying to use it in VBA, there's a separate add-in called Analysis Tookpak - VBA.  Make sure that's checked to use it in code.

Comment: Thanks, but that's just the problem - the analysis toolpak is installed, and works for other functions like FV.

Comment: That stinks.  PRICE worked in mine.  I wonder if your add-in file is corrupted.  It might be worth a shot to replace it.  I can email you a copy if you want to try it. dkusleika@gmail.com